# What happen to string.ToCommonSenseCase()?

Tags: strings, formatting, case-insensitivity

I'm very confused about this. In most programming languages, there are `string.ToUpperCase()`, `string.ToLowerCase()`, sometimes `Capitalize()` (which capitalize the first *letter of the string*), even `ToTitleCase()` which capitalize every first letter of everyword.

But why isn't there any `ToCommonSenseCase()`? The one that capitalize the first letter of each sentence? Why doesn't any language have it? I thought it should be the first utility function to implement case-wise.

Comment: see [On discussions and why they don't make good questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6742/31260)

Comment: It is not a discussion. There should be a reason why it isn't implemented in any languages I know. It shouldn't be a coincidence that all those languages creators have the same *opinion* of omitting it.

Comment: Since there is likely not to be a single answer which applies to all languages and their creators, and we must conjecture the reasons for this, I think it does count as s discussion.

Comment: Theres no such thing as common sense.

Comment: Because determining where sentence boundaries fall is deceptively difficult. Try writing a sentence boundary detector, and you'll have a hard time getting anywhere near 100%. Therefore it would take far too much code for a peripheral utility routine in the standard library,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's called [sentence case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Sentence_case), and there are some challenges with it:

- The word "I" needs to be capitalized, wherever it appears in the sentence. Granted, the programming language could detect that.
- [Proper nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_noun) ('names') always need to be capitalized. These are a lot harder to detect programmatically; a dictionary alone won't even help since "Mark" is both a name and a common word.
- A dot does not always signify the end of a sentence, e.g. when using abbreviations like this sentence does.
- Other languages than English have different capitalization rules: for example, German capitalizes *all* nouns.

You see that a proper sentence casing tool is much more complicated that just transforming each letter to capital or lowercase form; that's why standard libraries don't have this functionality.

Comment: Many languages have locale specific utilities for formatting numbers and dates.  Seems like the same could be done for basic sentence capitalization.

Comment: Then you get into [Why is quixotic not Quixotic (a proper adjective)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/486432) and decide a shot of Tequila sounds good about now.